# tensorflow works in ipython command line but not in notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow works for me in both python and ipython in command line, but when loading tensorflow using `import tensorflow`, it gives the following errors:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /usr/local/packages/python/2.7.10-anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

Here is the screenshot shows that tensorflow works in command line

[image]

Here is the screenshot shows that it doesn't work in notebook interface

[image]

So why does it work in command line but not in the notebook interface? I've compared the environment variable using `os.environ` and they looks the same in the command line and in notebook.

System information:

```
Linux qb2 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Sep 14 05:32:37 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tensorflow version:

```
0.11.0rc0
```

I don't think this is relevant, but the ipython kernel is on the remote machine `qb037`, and the notebook interface is on my local machine. The ipython kernel is started using

```
[mwu3@qb037 ~]$ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Then at my local machine, I set up the port forwarding as

```
ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 qb037
```

And the notebook interface is started from the browser at `localhost:8888`.

Comment: It looks like a glibc mismatch. Since this is a setup issue, please file an issue in [github](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues). Mention @drpngx there, and also please report as much as you can from the system: unix version, current libc, tensorflow version, etc.

Comment: @drpng OK I will file an issue there. But tensorflow works in command line interface, would that suggest a problem in ipython notebook somewhere?

Comment: We've had some issues with forwarding the library path in ipython, which does something funny. If you want to read up, here is the issue [on mac](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5141).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it breaks is because the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set corrected. I reported the problem to my system administrator, and he offered a solution that works:

```
module load gcc
```

Comparing before and after loading gcc, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does change. After loading the module, the following paths have been prepended to the PATH.

```
/usr/local/compilers/gcc/4.9.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0
/usr/local/compilers/gcc/4.9.0/lib64
/usr/local/compilers/gcc/4.9.0/lib
```